# Deploy SQL Server api with Express.js to Heroku

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express, heroku

I'm very new with Express.js, but right now i've created an api of SQL Server DB. It works fine on localhost, but now, i've deployed on Heroku. While my CMD prompt is open, my api works fine, but when it's close, i get an Internal Server Error.

Previously, i've created a test using Mongo as DB, mongoose and deployed to Heroku an the api still working even when the prompt isn't open. Someone knows if i have to create another .js document just like in mongoose or else to keep working my api?

This is my code on the .js document (server.js):

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const sql = require('mssql');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, contentType,Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    next();
});


const dbConfig = {
    user: "daUser",
    password: "daPass",
    server: "daServer",
    database: "DaDB"
}

const executeQuery = function (res, query) {
    sql.connect(dbConfig, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.send(err);
        }
        else {
            // create Request object
            var request = new sql.Request();
            // query to the database
            request.query(query, function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.send(err);
                }
                else {
                    res.send(result);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

app.get("/api/HolidayBaseApi", function (req, res) {
    var query = "SELECT * FROM [HolidaysBase]";
    executeQuery(res, query);
})

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("App now running on port", PORT);
});
```

My package.json next:

```
    {
  "name": "holidaysbaseapi",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Api of Holidays",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Chuck Villavicencio",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "mssql": "^4.3.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.11.3",
    "npm": "5.6.0"
  }
}
```

On Heroku i've installed the Heroku CLI; logged in, Clone the repository and deployed my changes.

I'm using Express.js, Node, SQL Server and Heroku

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your SQL server db is created on you local machine and heroku can't connect  to it. You can you the postgresDB provided by heroku or create the sql server db in any provider around the internet and replace the dbConfig with the configs of that db

Comment: Ok, but, this DB is on a "real" server. What i mean: it's a real DB that have already a server... still need to us postgresDB?

Comment: If you have a real db you just need to put the correct configuration of the database and it should work, Try to download a SQL cliente on you computer, put the same config you are using on this code and check if you can connect, if not, that's something wrong with the connection. Otherwise it should work